# Is there a workaround for using variables with LOAD XML LOCAL?

Tags: mysql

**BACKGROUND INFO:**
I have an XML feed that only lets me look up one product at a time, using a unique product ID.

I wrote a script that takes the results from the XML feed, puts them into a temporary Mysql table,  groups the results into one field and adds some formatting, then updates my main table with the new info and drops the temporary table.

It works great.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**
I have to do this for about 1000 products and I used LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE which I have just learned does not let you use variables etc in the address for the XML feed.

Which means that my script works great if I manually change the id in the feed address, then run it.

Unfortunately this is not so good when I have about 1000 product id's I need to run this script on. I have a separate table that contains the 1000 product id's ( called PRODUCT_ID_TABLE ).

**THE QUESTION:**
Is there a workaround that lets you effectively pass a variable to LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE?

Or another way to run the script for all product id's in my PRODUCT_ID_TABLE?

**CODE:**
I had to alter the feed address as i'm not allowed to share that.

```
/* set XML prodid into a variable */
SET @idinfo := ('17ENDUROEnduroSWCarbon650BLIMITEDFRM');

/* Creates my temporary table with 4 columns */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `SPEC_NAME` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SPEC_VALUE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `prodid` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `spec` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;

/* Loads my XML into SPEC_NAME and SPEC_VALUE */
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'http://FEEDADDRESSHERE.com/SBC/xml/FEEDNAMEHERE.jsp?feedType=getProductSpecs&productId=17ENDUROEnduroSWCarbon650BLIMITEDFRM'
INTO TABLE temp
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<SPECIFICATION>';

/* Concat SPEC_NAME and SPEC_VALUE into prodid, while also adding some formatting to be used later */
UPDATE temp SET prodid = CONCAT_WS(' ','<b>', NULLIF(TRIM(SPEC_NAME), ''),':</b>', NULLIF(TRIM(SPEC_VALUE), ''),'<br>');

/* group all rows from prodid together into one field value */
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @specinfo := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(prodid SEPARATOR ',') FROM temp GROUP BY NULL);

/* insert that value and xml product id uses access the xml into my temp table*/
insert into temp (prodid,spec) values(@idinfo,@specinfo);

/* Put the tyres info into a variable */
SET @tyres := (SELECT SPEC_VALUE FROM `temp` WHERE SPEC_NAME = 'FRONT TYRE');

/* update my main table with info from the temp table, then drop the temp table */
/* update product_id table with above values from temp table, where the product id's match */
UPDATE product_id t1 
        INNER JOIN temp t2 
             ON t1.ProductId = t2.prodid
SET t1.specification = t2.spec;

UPDATE product_id t1 
        INNER JOIN temp t2 
             ON t1.ProductId = t2.prodid
SET t1.tyres = @tyres;
DROP TABLE temp ;
```